# WM_GESTURE/WM_GESTURENOTIFY not dispatched on Windows 7 with iIyama plt2250 monitor. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: windows-7, touch, gestures

I've been tasked with adding gesture support to our product which was simple enough on a new Windows 8 machine - I just added WM_GESTURE to our wndproc and everything worked as expected.  However, when it came to getting it to work on a Win7 machine things have been very different.  I receive no gesture messages at all.  Even spy++ shows no gesture messages being sent to my application.  I've managed to get touch messages working using RegisterTouchWindow() but I know that I won't get an gesture messages when touch is disabled, so that was only done for test purposes.  I read somewhere that "flicks" can interfere, so I have disabled flicks, both from the control panel, and from code using SetOpt().  I've even tried hooking in to GetMessage using SetWindowsHookEx.  Nothing I do works.  I've tried the example programs from the Microsoft Touch Pack, and gestures appear to be working there, in that everything works as expected.  I've read all the documentation I can find, and still can't work out what's going wrong.  Can anyone provide any more insight into this?  I feel like it should "just work", but it really isn't!

Thanks in advance.